# Is a dereferenced pointer a valid lvalue?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

Assuming the definition:

```
int i  = 10;
int *p = &i;
```

Why is *p a valid lvalue here:

```
*p+=10;
```

Shouldn't *p evaluate to the value of the int stored at &i, ie. 10, and hence generate a "Not an lvalue" error?

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. I think this is a fine question

Comment: I always thought of `*p` as a synonym for `i`, and never ran into any confusion.

Comment: `*p` "evaluates to the value of the int stored at `&i`" when used as an rvalue.  But as an lvalue, it's the same as the lvalue `i`.

Comment: `*p` always means "the contents of the location pointed to by `p`". The difference between the interpretation of `*p` as an lvalue vs. an rvalue is that when `*p` appears as an lvalue it's understood that the intent is to *store into* the location pointed to by `p`, while when `*p` is used as an rvalue it's understood that the intent is to *retrieve the contents* of the memory location pointed to by `p`.

Comment: @Kevin - my internal mental reading of `*p` is "the object of the pointer p". A bit wordy, perhaps, but mentally this translates `*p += 10` into "the object of the pointer p is incremented by 10".

Comment: On a philosophical note, if `*p` always was an r-value, what would be the point of pointers? They'd be effectively read-only...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> An **lvalue** is an expression that refers to a region
>   of storage that can be manipulated.

`*p` is such an expression that refers to a region of storage.  This is different than say `10+=10;` because `10` doesn't refer to a region of storage like a variable would.

Comment: 10 is an expression. It is just not an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

[C11 6.5.3.2p4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4):

> **Semantics**
>
> ...
>
> 4. The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to *an* object, the result is an lvalue designating *the* object**. If the operand has type ''pointer to type'', the result has type ''type''. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined

I.e. with

```
int i  = 10;
int *p = &i;
```

the result of `*p` is an lvalue that designates the object `i`.

Therefore `*p += 10` works, as it is an lvalue.

Now, if an lvalue were used in a context where the object itself is needed, it would be *converted to the value stored in the designated object*. This is called *the lvalue conversion*, and the resulting value of course isn't an lvalue anymore ([C11 6.3.2.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2)).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are confused with the definition of `p`. `p` is, in fact, a variable of type *pointer to int*, and its value is initialized to the address of `i`.

Nonetheless, `*p` is a valid lvalue as well - a valid expression to a storage location.

Answer (score 2):

In very simple words, pointers point to an object (in a general, non OOP sense), not to the contents of that object. So yes, a dereferenced pointer is a valid lvalue.

In very low level terms. A pointer is nothing but a memory address, a dereferenced pointer is the memory at that address.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't `*p` evaluate to the value of the int stored at `&i`, ie. 10, and hence generate a "Not an lvalue" error?

In simple words,

`*` means "value at address".

`*p` means "value at address given by the value of `p`".

`*p = 10;` means "set 10 as the value at address given by the value of `p`".

lvalue is an expression that refers to an object stored somewhere in the memory. `*p` is also an expression that refers to an object stored at location `p`.