# Create a reference with new in C++

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code and it seems that to create a reference with new is okay, however when it comes to creating an object with new,  it crashes when i try to recollect the memory allocated

```
float &f = *new float(1.3);
delete &f;
float f1 = *new float;
delete &f1;
```

I'd like to know the difference, thanks !

Comment: References are not pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @H2CO3, but it seems the confusion here is that there are multiple operations involved. `new` allocated some memory and returns an address. E.g. you could have a line with `new float;` and it'd compile. The next part, `*new float` dereferences the pointer to obtain the value at that address. Assigning the value is another operation, which is unconnected to the `new` operator. The reference is initialized via the value (and its location), not `new`.

Comment: @jozxyqk That is because **references are not pointers.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3954803/1888983

Comment: I am curious how this is legally compiled... Isn't `*new something` an rvalue? How can you bind a rvalue to a lvalue reference???

Comment: @texasbruce Why would it be an rvalue? Dereferencing a pointer is lvalue, is not it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773839/is-a-dereferenced-pointer-a-valid-lvalue

Comment: @Suma Even the pointer itself is an rvalue (that is directly returned from a function)? So we have rvalue -> lvalue transition?

Comment: @texasbruce `*` dereferences a pointer, regardless of r/lvalue. E.g. `*ptr = *otherPtr;` to copy the values. This also compiles `*new float = *new float(1.3f);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, "creating a reference with new" isn't exactly what you're doing. To understand this, the code needs to be broken up...

```
new float(1.3);
```

this allocates 4 bytes of memory for a float, constructs the float using a 1.3 double constant, and returns a pointer to the start of the memory - the first of the 4 bytes.

```
*new float(1.3);
```

this "dereferences" the pointer returned by the new operator, so instead of reading the pointer value, you're reading the 4-byte `float` data it points to.

```
float &f = *new float(1.3);
```

constructs a reference f, using the `float` provided by new. While (AFAIK) references are implemented as pointers with greater potential for compiler optimizations (?), this is one part people are complaining about. Conceptually, the reference *is* the float and you shouldn't be assuming you can retrieve the address, free the memory and hence invalidate the reference later.

However, as you have found, it does actually work and you can retrieve the address...

```
&f
```

produces a pointer to the memory at the reference's location, which you can then

```
delete &f;
```

---

To answer your actual question...

```
float f1 = *new float;
```

can be rewritten as follows

```
float f1; //a float on the stack!
f1 = *new float; //should probably be: *new float(1.3)
```

which does not initialize a reference, but instead **copies** the data allocated by new to the float on the stack. After the copy, the memory address returned by `new` is lost forever - you have "leaked" memory.

Now on to why it crashes.

```
&f1;
```

creates a pointer to the float `f1`, on the stack. This memory has not been created by `new` or the memory allocation library new ultimately uses. Attempting to free a memory address that doesn't exist in the memory allocation library...

```
delete &f1;
```

...results in your crash.

The *difference* between `float &f` and `float f1`: one is a reference, internally implemented as a pointer (which is assumed never to change) and one is an actual float variable declared on the stack which does not reference other memory.

What you should be doing instead is

```
float *f = new float(1.3f);
// access f as *f = 1.2f or cout << *f
delete f;
```

Comment: My original understanding of why the delete &f crashes is it illegally retrieves the memory that is allocated out of Stack using delete  which is supposed to retrieve memory allocated only from the heap. After your cogent explanation, my thought is justified ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
float f1 = *new float;
```

It creates a object of type `float` on free store and then copies the original object to `f1`. You lose the address of the original free store object, this gives you a instant memory leak.

All memory de-allocation functions mandate that address being passed to them should be same as the one returned by memory allocation functions, so you end up with an **undefined behavior** when you call `delete` on a address not returned through `new`.

Note that an Undefined behavior doesn't mandate a crash, but absence of a crash doesn't mean there ir no problem in the code.

Comment: In regard to the first part, it looks like `&f` will produce the same address as returned by `new`. Is this guaranteed? (not saying this should be done, just interested in the way references are implemented)

Comment: @jozxyqk: It is not the same. Either case you end up losing the address to the original object.

Comment: So you're saying that after `float &f = *new float(1.3);`, `&f` will return a different address? I think it returns the *same* address, just not certain it is guaranteed.

Comment: `float *p = new float; float &f = *p; printf("%p %p\n", p, &f);` gives `0x1679010 0x1679010`.

Comment: @jozxyqk: They are not equivalent, You can see the difference in the another answer posted here.

Comment: Well, I compiled `float *f = new float; delete f;` and `float &f = *new float; delete &f;`. Both produce the same assembly output and `valgrind` reports no leaks. In practice, with `g++` they are identical in implementation, though I can't be certain the same would happen with different compilers.